# Keyboard位置操作について

Tags: swift, ios, xcode, iphone

Swiftで，キーボードの位置操作は行えるのでしょうか．例えば普段下に出てきているキーボードを上に表示するなどを行いたいです．検索してもキーボードの位置を取得するのみや，テキストフィールドを動かすなどの記事しか見つかりません．よろしくお願いいたします

Answer (score 1, accepted):

キーボードの表示される位置を変えることはできません。
iOSにおいてキーボードのコントロールはかなり制限されていて、表示された・非表示になったタイミング、あるいはキーボードの大きさくらいが知ることができるもので、動作に干渉するようなことはほとんどできません。

Comment: やはりそうなのですね....ご回答ありがとうございます